# Get Category Description in my cutom phtml file in magento 2

Tags: categories, magento2, descriptor

I am using Magento 2. I want to get category description and image in my custom phtml file.
How can i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get in current category information in phtml you can use following code.

```
<?php
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$currentCategory = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_category');//get current category information
echo $currentCategory->getId();
echo $currentCategory->getName();
echo $currentCategory->getDescription();
echo $currentCategory->getImageUrl();
?>
```

Or do you want to load any specific category then you can use below code.

```
$categoryId = 3;
$_objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$category = $_objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')
->load($categoryId);
echo $category->getName();
echo $category->getImageUrl();
```

Comment: How to get category image?

Comment: this will get the url. Does this will print the image?

Comment: Yes this will give you the url you can use that url in image tag. And if you want magento default image out put then you have to use $_outputhelper    = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');

Comment: If above solution solve your problem then please upvote it.

Comment: thanx, this worked. Can u tell me how to avoid printing the description and image from default position on category page?

Comment: Go to this file app/design/frontend/Company_Name/Theme_Name/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_category_view.xml and find <referenceBlock name="category.description" /> this and replace with it <referenceBlock name="category.description" remove="true"/>